# Auto create related object in db using before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

In my application I have a Question model and a QuestionResult model. They are related through a Question has_one QuestionResult and I am trying to get Rails to auto create its related QuestionResult entry when I am creating the Question entry.

Here is what I have tried in the Question model:

```
before_create :create_result_record_and_populate_difficulty

has_one :question_result, :dependent => :destroy

def create_result_record_and_populate_difficulty
  self.build_question_result(:current_difficulty => initial_difficulty)
end
```

Initial difficulty is simply an attribute of the Question model which I am using to set the current difficulty in the associated QuestionResult model. I know the method is being called because I have placed an "raise" statement within the method and it triggers the exception when I run "rake db:seed" to add some questions.

However, no QuestionResult entries are found in the db even if the db seeding is successful.

Is there anything wrong with the way this should be done? Please help enlighten me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `build` method which constructs a new object without saving it to the database. Try:

```
def create_result_record_and_populate_difficulty
  self.create_question_result(:current_difficulty => initial_difficulty)
end
```

The create method actually inserts the new record into the database. For has_one relationships ActiveRecord provides a create and a build method. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually I used build because I was using the before_create method. If I had used the create instead of build with before_create, it would complain because the Question object would not have been assigned an id, which is a required field for the QuestionResult object. Once the save is called on the Question object, it would automatically save the QuestionResult object as well. However, your answer has helped me find the problem - it was an additional QuestionResult.deleteAll in my seeds.rb Thanks!